# Build web service with jax-ws reference implemetation bundled in JDK 6

Tags: java, jax-ws

I used to saw a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/) about this topic. But when I try to make my example application by following the example. I can't find `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener` on my classpath.
but I found `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener`
It confused me, why Oracle move those classes in `com.sun.xml.xxx` to `com.sun.xml.internal`? I am using JDK1.6.0_45. I saw some people said, form JDK6U4, jax-ws reference implementation is bundled in JDK, so we should be able to publish a web service by running a light weight http server just with JDK and no other dependencies needed, is that ture? You should notice that in the tutorial I mentioned above, additional dependencies is still needed, see step 5 "JAX-WS Dependencies".

And I also found that in IBM JDK, even `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener` can't be found.

Comment: That tutorial you linked is based on a glassfish implementation of JAX-WS, [Metro](https://metro.java.net/guide/). Vanilla JDK doesn't ship with `WSServletContextListener`, that's strictly JavaEE. If you're looking at building a web service without a web app server,  [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860588/java-web-service-without-a-web-application-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JAX-WS RI (same as JAX-B RI) is shipped with JDK since Jdk6. All the packages except for javax.xml.* are changed to *.internal.* in order to avoid conflicts between JDK's and standalone JAX-WS versions.

Using JDK's version, you can deploy web service using just JDK; if you want deploy WS in tomcat or in some AS, you still need JAX-WS standalone version.

Answer (score 0):

If you check grepcode for [(non-internal) WSServletContextListener](http://grepcode.com/search?query=com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener&start=0&entity=type&n=#), it shows you, the class is shipped with jaxws-rt/webservice-rt jar.

By looking for the [internal WSServletContextListener](http://grepcode.com/search?query=com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener&start=0&entity=type&n=#), you can't find a jar shipping it. (but grepcode also contains the sources of openJDK)

Also, I tried to find WSServletContextListener in my local jdk7, but can't find it. But maybe some third-party jdk ship with the class.

Anyway, if you look into the tutorial again, you will find that jaxws-rt.jar is necessery for the application. Probably you should add it?